# Is there a way to call findMatch recursively?

Tags: java, recursion, option-type, predicate, supplier

In this question, I am required to write a findMatch method that takes in a "stream" (IFL is meant to mimic a stream) and finds the first element of the stream that passes a Predicate. My attempt is as follows:

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class IFL<T> {
    Supplier<T> head;
    Supplier<IFL<T>> tail;

    IFL(Supplier<T> head, Supplier<IFL<T>> tail) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    static <T> IFL<T> of(List<? extends T> list) {
        return new IFL<T>(
            () -> list.get(0),
            () -> IFL.of(list.subList(1, list.size()))) {
        };
    }       

    Optional<T> findMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        if (predicate.test(head.get())) {
            return Optional.of(this.head.get());
        } else {
            if (this.tail.get().findMatch(predicate).isPresent()) {
                return this.tail.get().findMatch(predicate);
            }
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the `else` block in my findMatch method seems to only run the `return` statement instead of recursively calling itself like i believe it should. Is there anyway to ensure that it does?

Update: i have gotten the code to work for the second line of input. However, running the third line of input produces an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in jshell.

The input is as follows

```
    IFL<String> list = IFL.of(Arrays.asList("three", "little", "pigs"))
    list.findMatch(str -> str.length() == 6)
    list.findMatch(str -> str.length() < 4)
```

Comment: Recursion is to call the method by itself, it dont need the reference variable to invoke.

Comment: here a kind of recursion is happening but the results are not utilized. Because it was not assigned to a variable nor returned.

Comment: what's your sample input to the program?

Comment: @Naman I have added the input to the post

Comment: @sarathkumar right, i have made some adjustments but ran into further issues, included an update in the original post

Comment: another sample of poor recursion is the code `return new IFL<T>(
            () -> list.get(0),
            () -> IFL.of(list.subList(1, list.size()))) {
        };`, how do you expect this to end with the `list.get(0)` as a hardcoded access?

Comment: @Zulu i have posted the solution for this, kindly let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

By checking list size in the constructor and also checking nullity for   `this.head` in the `findMatch()` method;

You don't need to check `if (this.tail.get().findMatch(predicate).isPresent())` and then call again `findMatch` method.

```
class IFL<T> {
   Supplier<T> head;
   Supplier<IFL<T>> tail;

   IFL(Supplier<T> head, Supplier<IFL<T>> tail) {
     this.head = head;
     this.tail = tail;
   }

   static <T> IFL<T> of(List<? extends T> list) {

     if (list.isEmpty())
         return new IFL<>(null, null);

     return new IFL<T>(
            () -> list.get(0),
            () -> IFL.of(list.subList(1, list.size()))) {
     };
   }

  Optional<T> findMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
     if (this.head == null)
        return Optional.empty();
     return predicate.test(head.get()) ?
         Optional.of(this.head.get()) :this.tail.get().findMatch(predicate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown for an illegal endpoint index value for the `List#subList` method `(fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size || fromIndex > toIndex)`

in your `IFL#of` method, you need to check if the given list is of size 1. If so, set `tail` to an empty list.

```
static <T> IFL<T> of(List<? extends T> list) {
 return new IFL<T>(
     () -> list.get(0),
     () -> IFL.of(list.size == 1 ? new ArrayList<T>() : list.subList(1, list.size()))) {
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

class IFL<T> {
    Supplier<T> head;
    Supplier<IFL<T>> tail;
    List<? extends T> list;

    IFL(Supplier<T> head, Supplier<IFL<T>> tail, List<? extends T> list) {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static <T> IFL<T> of(List<? extends T> list) {
        return new IFL<T>(
                () -> list.get(0),
                () -> IFL.of(list.subList(1, list.size())), list) {
        };
    }

    Optional<T> findMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        if (!list.isEmpty() && predicate.test(head.get())) {
            return Optional.of(this.head.get());
        } else {
            if (!list.isEmpty() && this.tail.get().findMatch(predicate).isPresent()) {
                return this.tail.get().findMatch(predicate);
            }
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String...args) {
        IFL<String> list = IFL.of(Arrays.asList("three", "little", "pigs"));
        System.out.println(list.findMatch(str -> str.length() == 6));
        System.out.println(list.findMatch(str -> str.length() < 4));
    }
}
```

Hope This helps !!!